# Select nested data using crosstalk and filter_select

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a nested data.frame that looks similar to this example. I want to use crosstalk filter_select to return the nested plot from the 'selected' Species. How do I access the 'selected' shared data in crosstalk?

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(crosstalk)

    irisplot= iris %>% 
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      nest %>% 
      mutate(plot = map2(Species, data,  function (.x,.y){
      ggplot(data = .y, aes(x =  Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_smooth() +
      ggtitle(label = .x) }))

    shared_df1 <- SharedData$new(irisplot, ~Species, group = "Choose")

    bscols( 
    filter_select("species", 
    "Species:",shared_df1,~Species,multiple=FALSE),

    shared_df1$data$plot ## does not work. What should this be?

    )
```